# "Cannot read property 't' of undefined" error when using vuetify v-carousel component

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm currently working on an image carousel with Laravel and Vue/Vuetify and I'm using the Vuetify v-carousel and v-carousel-item to achieve this, except that the carousel is not rendering because of the error in the title.

I've already properly initialized my Vuetify instance (I think) based on the vuetify documentation

--code below is for my app.js--

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify, {VCarousel} from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
    components: {
      VCarousel,
    },
  })

// export default new Vuetify({})

const app = new Vue({
}).$mount('#app');
```

--and the code below is for the component that uses the carousel--

```
<template>
    <v-carousel>
      <v-carousel-item v-for="(slide, i) in slides" :src = "slide.content " :key=i>
      </v-carousel-item>
      <v-carousel-item>
          <!-- <v-playback autoPlay :url = "video" :type="video/mp4" :width = "720" @play = "pauseCarousel" @pause = "playCarousel" ref = 'videoPlayer'></v-playback> -->
      </v-carousel-item>
    </v-carousel>
</template>
```

And that gives me this error

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 't' of undefined"

found in

---> <VCarousel>
       <ImageCarousel> at resources/js/components/ImageCarousel.vue
         <ExampleComponent> at resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue
           <Root>
```

Comment: You're getting this error because you're *probably* using firefox. Switch to chrome and you'll get a *real* error message.

Comment: Additionally you may get `Cannot read property`  some letter `of undefined` when you build the project in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm going to go ahead and assume you're using firefox*

> “Cannot read property 't' of undefined” error when using vuetify v-carousel component

This type of error is commonly found with [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) because it is unable to properly read the source mapping of your transpiled project thus giving that error.

I had the same issue with a typescript project.

I recommend (for now) switching to [chrome](/questions/tagged/chrome) for debuging, which will give you the *real* error message in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers but I managed to get everything working by starting a new project and then manually importing all the components I needed for the project. Everything's working fine now, however I ran into another bump here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57605363/laravel-vuetify-needs-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type-mp4