# Laravel/Vuetify needs an appropriate loader to handle this file type (mp4)

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js

I'm currently working on a Laravel/Vue image carousel and the images are rendering fine but when I load the videos using the v-playback component, I get the following error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character ' ' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this
file type, currently no loaders are configured to
process this file.
```

I've tried looking for a webpack.config.js but what I got is a webpack.mix.js which only has these:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

I did manage to find a webpack.config.js in the laravel-mix folder in node_modules but I'm not sure if that's the one I need to be tinkering with.

Comment: What version of vuetify you are using?

Comment: This is what I found in my Package.json

"vuetify": "^2.0.9"

Comment: https://github.com/avgkudey/LaraVuetify

Comment: Refer this starter template

Comment: I'm getting a 500 server error after running all the installs. I'm using Laragon for my virtual host. Accessing it using Browsersync's access URL also gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your url is pointing to the exact path and file extension where the video is located . Your url should probably point to something like this ../public/videos/name_of_video.mp4